# return hex color from int interval (0,100) between two colors

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm trying to create an animated health bar in my web game, which should change it color when increases our decreases. The health bar can have values between 0 and 100. the color when it reaches 0 is "#FF0000" and when it's full it should have the color "#00FF00". I only need the logic to convert this int number to a hex string.

Obs: I'm using pure Javascript. I want to do without any plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that such a conversion is not required for the realization of your idea, and solutions with other color models are quite suitable:

```js
function fRGB(obj) {
  let nVal = +obj.value;
  obj.style.boxShadow = `inset 0 0 7px 6px rgb(${255 - nVal * 2.55}, ${nVal * 2.55}, 0)`;
}

function fHSL(obj) {
  let nVal = +obj.value;
  obj.style.boxShadow = `inset 0 0 7px 6px hsl(${nVal * 1.2}, 100%, 50%)`;
}
```

```html
RGB<br><input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="fRGB(this)">
<br>
HSL<br><input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="fHSL(this)">
```

Note that the color, with average values of the sliders, varies in different models.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```js
const valueToColor = value => {
  let gHex = Math.round(value * 255 / 100) // rule of three to calibrate [0, 100] to [00, FF] (= [0, 255])
  let rHex = 255 - gHex // just the mirror of gHex
  gHex = gHex.toString(16) // converting to traditional hex representation
  rHex = rHex.toString(16)
  gHex = gHex.length === 1 ? `0${gHex}` : gHex // compensating missing digit in case of single digit values
  rHex = rHex.length === 1 ? `0${rHex}` : rHex
  return `#${rHex}${gHex}00` // composing both in a color code
}

console.log(valueToColor(0)) // #ff0000
console.log(valueToColor(100)) // #00ff00
console.log(valueToColor(50)) // #7f8000
console.log(valueToColor(23)) // #c43b00
console.log(valueToColor(85)) // #26d900
```

I think that's an easier and shorter solution than the ones presented in similar threads.

Interactive snippet example :

```js
const valueToColor = value => {
  let gHex = Math.round(value * 255 / 100) // rule of three to calibrate [0, 100] to [00, FF] (= [0, 255])
  let rHex = 255 - gHex // just the mirror of gHex
  gHex = gHex.toString(16) // converting to traditional hex representation
  rHex = rHex.toString(16)
  gHex = gHex.length === 1 ? `0${gHex}` : gHex // compensating missing digit in case of single digit values
  rHex = rHex.length === 1 ? `0${rHex}` : rHex
  return `#${rHex}${gHex}00` // composing both in a color code
}

//

const slider = document.getElementById('life')
const colorDiv = document.getElementById('color')
const valueDiv = document.getElementById('value')

const setValue = () => {
  const color = valueToColor(slider.value)
  colorDiv.style.backgroundColor = color
  valueDiv.innerText = color
 }

setValue()
slider.addEventListener('input', setValue)
```

```css
#life {
  width: 50%;
}

#color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="95" id="life">
<div id='color'/>
<h2 id='value'/>
```